# Select the column name of a reactive dataframe and update it with a textInput()

Tags: r, shiny

In the `shiny` app below I upload a dataset,so its a reactive dataset, and then I get a `selectInput()` with its column names. Then I should be able to select a column and change it with the `textInput()` after hitting the `actionButton()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")
    ),
    uiOutput("column"),
    textInput("text", label = "Set column name", placeholder = "Enter text..."),
    actionButton("sub","submit")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    dataTableOutput("process")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  raw<-reactive({
    
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = T)
  })
  
  output$column<-renderUI({
    selectInput("col","Pick a column to change its name",
                choices = colnames(raw()))
  })
  mydf <- reactiveValues(df = raw(), names = names(raw()))
  
  observeEvent(input$sub, {
    req(input$text)
    mydf$names[mydf$names == input$col] <- input$text
    names(mydf$df) <- mydf$names
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "col", choices = mydf$names)
  })
  output$process<-renderDataTable({
    mydf$df
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your line:

```
mydf <- reactiveValues(df = raw(), names = names(raw()))
```

And replaced it with:

```
  mydf <- reactiveValues(df = NULL, names = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(raw(), {
    if(!is.null(raw())) {
      mydf$df <- raw()
      mydf$names <- names(raw())
    }
  })
```

And for me it functions as how I think you wanted it. The primary issue is it would crash for me upon start. As you wrote it, it tries to access `raw()` immediately and put it in the `reactiveValues`. Thus, by making the `reactiveValues` NULL by default, and then only adding it in when `raw()` exists, it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible approach. Maybe there are better options. Just replace `iris` with your input data. It should work.

A general advice is to avoid function names as object names for reactive objects, such as `raw()` which is a function, but also the name of a reactive in your example. It makes things more difficult to debug and it will throw error messages which don't make sense, if you forget that `raw()` is also a function.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    # fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
    #           accept = c(
    #             "text/csv",
    #             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
    #             ".csv")
    # ),
    uiOutput("column"),
    textInput("text", label = "Set column name", placeholder = "Enter text..."),
    actionButton("sub","submit")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    dataTableOutput("process")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  mydf <- reactiveValues(names = NULL)
  
  raw_df <- reactive({
    
    mydat <- iris # here goes the input file
    
    iris_nms <- mydf$names
    
    if(!is.null(iris_nms)) {
      names(mydat) <- iris_nms
    }
    
    mydat
  })
  
  output$column <- renderUI({
    selectInput("col","Pick a column to change its name",
                choices = colnames(raw_df()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$sub, {
    req(input$text)
    org_names <- names(raw_df())
    org_names[org_names == input$col] <- input$text
    mydf$names <- org_names

  })

  output$process<-renderDataTable({
    raw_df()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I had never used ```raw()``` before, that's a really good point about avoiding the use of already existing function names!